# Как изменить клас через медиазапрос?

Tags: css, вёрстка, bootstrap, адаптивная-верстка

В бутстрапе есть встроенный класс для вертикального и горизонтального расположения группы кнопок, нужно сделать в мобильном виде кнопки в вертикальном расположении, а в десктопном виде - горизонтальные. 
Вышел из положения создав блоки которые скрываются в определенном расширении через классы hidden:

```
    <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-8 hidden-md hidden-lg" style="text-align: right; float:right">
    <div class="btn-group-vertical navbar-fixed-right header-menu">
    ...
    </div></div>

    <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-8  hidden-sm hidden-xs" style="text-align: right; float:right">
    <div class="btn-group navbar-fixed-right header-menu">
    ...
    </div></div>
```

Можно ли сделать тоже самое через медиазапросы в css? 
Т.е изменить класс элемента в css при определенном разширении экрана что бы не плодить кучу лишнего кода?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно точно так же, как сделали Вы через bootstrap, надо добавить внизу Вашего css медиазапрос, а в нем создать класс который будет скрываться при разрешении от sm до xs, и применить этот класс к Вашему div. Если есть необходимость, могу написать код. Выгода только одна: на один класс меньше в каждом div.

Comment: Для себя сделал ту же задачу сделал эту же задачу так же через медиазапросы, но остановился на лишних 2х дивах. Тут в файлах проекта бардака с css еще больше(4 разных человека которые не особо шарят в верстке делают каждый свой кусок сайта по своему, поэтому тут некоторые страницы на сетке бутстрапа, некоторые в виде таблиц и все это с десятками перекрывающих друг друга стилей), поэтому остановился на лишнем диве.